# How to restrict access to a web site from a particular geographical area

Tags: web-hosting

I want to restrict all the users from a particular geographical area from accessing my web site.

Comment: You can configure the firewall to block all IPs from certain country. But people who care enough will be able to access anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to do this:

```
   <?php 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$file = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/?ip={$ip}");
 if(stristr($file, 'bad country') === FALSE) {
    echo 'ya\'ll may visit this here site.';
  }

else {
echo "nope!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Ben, have you tested it? I am getting '504 Gateway Time-out' error.